# Quel est le rôle de « en » dans « en saisir l'application »?

Tags: usage, en

Dans un livre, la phrase anglaise ci-après

> I was able to grasp its application.

est traduite par

> J'ai pu **en** saisir l'application.

Je ne comprends pas la présence de **en**. On aurait attendu

> J'ai pu saisir son application.

n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: Que signifie *application* dans la phrase anglaise ? Une *application*, en français*, n'est pas le genre de truc qu'on saisit...

Comment: Désolé, il n'y a pas d'autres détails. C'est la phrase anglaise accompagnée par la traduction. Ces deux phrases appartiennent dans une section portant le titre *En used in a possessive sense*.

Comment: *I was able to grasp its signification* = *J'ai pu en comprendre la signification* = *J'ai pu comprendre sa signification*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lorsqu'il s'agit d'un pronom, *en* a toujours la même fonction : il représente un complément introduit par *de*, que ce soit explicite ou implicite.

> **en** saisir l'application
>   
> = saisir l'application **de ce truc**

Ceci est l'une des possibilités pour former le génitif, ta construction étant l'autre et pas moins valide. Tu peux t'en servir des deux comme tu veux.

S'il y a une différence, ce serait que « son application » a tendance à suggérer l'application que quelqu'un a faite, et « l'application de ce truc » la manière d'appliquer qui lui est propre. Mais c'est une très vague impression — je souligne que chacun des génitifs peut porter l'un ou l'autre sens.

**Révision:** Et voir les commentaires de jlliagre ci-dessous pour découvrir un problème avec cette expression quant à son idiomaticité.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai clarifié !

Comment: La tournure **J'ai pu saisir son application.** est-elle complètement fausse ?

Comment: Non, elle est complètement juste (grammaticalement parlant), comme l'a écrit Luke.

Comment: @jlliagre Corrigé, merci. Approuves-tu le nouveau paragraphe final ?

Comment: Le problème est plutôt avec *saisir une application* qui n'a pas beaucoup de sens en français. Quel est le sens d'application dans *grasp its application* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Comprendre pour quoi c'est fait.

Comment: Ah, d'accord. On peut utiliser *application* avec ce sens en français dans *une application de cette découverte peut être...* ou *les applications de xxx sont*, mais *saisir son application* ou même *comprendre son application* ne sont pas idiomatiques ni vraiment compréhensibles. On dirait plutôt *comprendre l'objet de...* ou *comprendre l'utilisation possible de...*, *comprendre l'intérêt de...*

Comment: Peut-être des trucs comme _la mise en pratique_ et _à quoi est destinée concrètement telle chose_ voire sa _pertinence_. cc @jlliagre Merci !