# Understanding “en comprend”

Tags: sens, pronoms, locutions, en

I’m having trouble making sense of the “en” in “en comprend(re)” in examples such as the following:

- Si on **en** comprend les règles, on pourra les arrêter.
- Et lorsqu'on lit bien la loi, on **en** comprend toute la portée généreuse.
- En enquêtant sur chaque incident, on **en** comprend mieux les causes et on peut alors intervenir pour les atténuer ou pour les supprimer.

(Each example taken from here: https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/on+en+comprend)

What follows *en* seems to explain what’s to be understood, so *en* seems redundant. As a learner of French, the idiomatic *en* has been one of my biggest struggles to understand and internalize.

Comment: question déjà posée: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/30772/17649

Comment: Merci beaucoup et pardon. Y a-t-il un moyen de savoir si une question similaire ont déjà été posée pour que ne pas la répéter ?

Comment: J'ai bien peur que non ; je connais un seul moyen : ouvrir un tag, comme dans le présent cas le tag « en », puis lire les titres et vérifier toute questions qui présentent une analogie ou qui sont tout simplement une reformulation. By the way , don't feel guilty, no harm done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, *en* is a pronoun that replaces the possessive phrase (*complément du nom*) of a direct object.

In your examples:

- *"On comprend la portée généreuse **de la loi**"* becomes *"On **en** comprend la portée généreuse"*.
- *"On comprend mieux les causes **de chaque incident**"* becomes *"On **en** comprend mieux les causes"*.
- For the first example, we don't know what the pronoun replaces, but we can see it in your link, in the English version. It is *"Si on comprend les règles **de la compétition**"* which becomes *"Si on **en** comprend les règles"*.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Steph's answer, here is an alternate way to get rid of ***en***, using a possessive adjective:

> Et lorsqu'on lit bien la loi, on **en** comprend toute **la** portée généreuse.
>
> ↣   ..., on comprend toute **sa** portée généreuse
>
> En enquêtant sur chaque incident, on **en** comprend mieux **les** causes et on peut alors intervenir pour les atténuer ou pour les supprimer.
>
> ↣ ..., on comprend mieux **ses** causes et...